I accidentally rename lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1 file on my target machine, what should i do?
I accidentally renamed ld-linux-aarch64.so.1. Now I cannot connect my target machine with SSH. How can I rename it back? I will not consider to reflash my target machine.

If booting the system on your computer architecture involves an initramfs and you can get a shell from there (like maybe by passing break=bottom to the kernel command line), you could rename that file back from there. Without knowing even which OS or computer architecture, it's hard to give more detailed advise.

the OS is ubuntu. I can access the physical machine with minicom i think. but I am not sure if i can still use other command like mv

Boot live system, mount disk, mv
